# warning: 'struct curl_fileinfo' declared inside parameter list

Tags: c++, c, linux, curl, libcurl

My code is as follows:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
struct callback_data {
         FILE *output;
         char *path; //to specify the entire path
         char *fname; //Full file name of current download
         char *msg; //message for display
};              

static long file_is_comming(struct curl_fileinfo *finfo, struct callback_data *data, int remains);

static long file_is_downloaded(struct callback_data *data);

static size_t write_it(char *buff, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                       struct callback_data *data);

static long file_is_comming(struct curl_fileinfo *finfo, struct callback_data *data, int remains)
{
         printf("%3d %40s %10luB ", remains, finfo->filename, (unsigned long)finfo->size);

         printf("dest path = %s \n", data->path);
         if(finfo->filetype == CURLFILETYPE_FILE) {

                 data->fname = (char *)malloc( (sizeof(char *)) *
                                 (strlen(finfo->filename) + strlen(data->path)+1));

                 sprintf(data->fname, "%s%s", data->path, finfo->filename);
                 data->output = fopen(data->fname, "w");
         printf("dest file name = %s \n", data->fname);

                 if(!data->output) {
                         return CURL_CHUNK_BGN_FUNC_FAIL;
                 }
         }

         return CURL_CHUNK_BGN_FUNC_OK;
}
```

The warnings are:

```
warning: 'struct curl_fileinfo' declared inside parameter list
warning: 'struct curl_fileinfo' declared inside parameter list
utils-curl.h:15: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
utils-curl.c:3: warning: 'struct curl_fileinfo' declared inside parameter list
utils-curl.c:4: error: conflicting types for 'file_is_comming'
utils-curl.h:15: error: previous declaration of 'file_is_comming' was here
```

Comment: Try including the proper header.

Comment: Google suggests `#include <curl/curl.h>`, or forward-declare like @Dave said.

Comment: that i have include ... ( Plesae take it by default )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either include the proper header, or forward declare `struct curl_fileinfo` prior to using a pointer to it in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do in the following lines may not be what you want to do!

```
10                 data->fname = (char *)malloc( (sizeof(char *)) *
11                                 (strlen(finfo->filename) + strlen(data->path)+1));
```

I think you want to do

```
10                 data->fname = (char *)malloc( (sizeof(char)) *
11                                 (strlen(finfo->filename) + strlen(data->path)+1));
```

`sizeof(char)` and *not* `sizeof(char *)`

You must type cast the output of `sizeof()` to `int` because `sizeof()` returns `size_t` and not `int`.

OTOH, before using the malloc'ed memory you *must* check whether `malloc()` is successful or not!

Apart from the warnings, I think you should also look into the following errors:

```
    utils-curl.c:4: error: conflicting types for 'file_is_comming'
    utils-curl.h:15: error: previous declaration of 'file_is_comming' was here
```